# Соединение между клиентом и сервером WPF C#.NET

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, сервер

У меня две программы Клиент программа и Сервер программа написанные на WPF C#.NET. Сервер программа будет стоять на Dedicated Server.
1. Мне хочется понять, как мне быть если я хочу знать через одного клиента  что другой онлайн, для этого подойдет сокет TcpClient? Если да, то это нормально чтоб он постоянно был подключен вить в какойто момент я подключюсь к клиенту(клиент к клиентy) и начну передовать данные (1кб - 5кб размер, 1/1сек до 20/1сек пакетов).
2. Но скажем у меня клиентов много пускай 10к, все они будут подключены к одному TcpListener соккету? Или на каждую тысячу по TcpListener?
3. Ну и как быть если скажем если у меня несколько Dedicated Server серверов(Europe, Asia, USA) как объединить все сервера между собой.

спасибо за любую помощь.

Answer (score 0):

1. Клиентам нужно периодически опрашивать сервер на предмет изменений (если их много то можно использовать RabbitMq), на котором при подключении автоматом оповещаются все заинтересованные объекты. В любом случае надо подключаться к серверу чтобы узнать статус нужного клиента и его IP. TcpClient  вполне подойдет для этих целей.
2. Тут однозначного ответа нет, может и один TcpListener, а может и несколько "висящих" на разных IP адресах, а может стоять балансироващик, который распределяет запросы по серверам в зависимости от их загруженности. В любом случае обычно при подключении к TcpListener, запускается отдельный поток для работы с клиентом.
3. Тут вопрос архитектуры, может есть смысл сделать один балансировщик для распределения запросов между серверами, какая-то шина для их взаимодействия и какое-то единое хранилище данных. Во многом все же построение такой системы зависит от конкретной ситуации и выполняемых задач, поэтому какого-то единого решения нет.